# Using wget to download all pictures in a directory requiring authentication

Tags: command-line, 16.04, wget

I am trying to use wget to download all files in a series of directories on a site which requires authentication. The files are jpgs, and in this example there are 21 in the first directory I am currently accessing. Here is the command I am using, tell me what I am doing wrong...

```
wget --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD -nd -r -P /home/chris/Desktop/folder/ -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://website.com/directory/{001..021}.jpg
```

Comment: So it seems that with either trying to get one image or multiple it keeps returning images that can not be read. Could this be something with the site I'm getting the images from? What should I try next?